# Oil Level Citroen C1

Tags: oil, diesel, citroen

Hi I've got a Citroen C1 1.4HDI rythym. I think that the engine oil is filled too high. I checked the oil after letting the car heat up and having it on a level surface. I took it to a garage where the mechanic told me it was fine, but I am not convinced. I've included pictures of the dipstick:

[image]
[image]

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking it the oil level is where the Blue/Red arrow is at? If so, it should be down between the two green lines. If it is this high, I'd have some drained out. I'm not sure how much this would equate to, but would suggest it's in the arena of around 1/2 quart or liter. While many would think it's not a bad thing to have a little too much oil, it can cause problems, such as the crank shaft/connecting rod hitting the oil as it rotates. This would have a noticeable affect on fuel mileage and on longevity of the rod bearings. Here's my rendered image:

[image]

If the oil level is a lot closer (pretty hard to tell in your image) to the top green line, I'd suggest it probably wouldn't be an issue. A *little* bit of extra oil won't hurt anything, but any more than about an 1/8 quart/liter is probably too much in my approximation. This is not a hard and fast rule, per se ... it's just something I wouldn't allow with my car. Every car is going to be different as far as the maximum tolerance it might withstand ... that is mainly going to depend on how much oil it takes to fill it up in the first place (ie: A semi truck diesel engine holds gallons of oil ... a 1/2 quart extra will not make any difference with it.)